# rsyslog adding unwanted text to outbound log data

Tags: centos, rsyslog, apache-httpd

I'm using rsyslog to send access & error log data to a remote server.  The interface is in place, but I'm getting an extra bit of text in the outbound log data that isn't included in `/var/log/http/access_log`.

Here's a snippet from an access_log entry.  1.1.1.1 is my IP address, and 99.99.99.99 is the appserver's IP.

> 1.1.1.1 99.99.99.99 - - [29/Jun/2015:11:57:58 -0400] "GET /somepage.php HTTP/1.1" 200 443 20

Corresponding outbound log data sent by rsyslog using
`tcpdump -vv -s 0 -A dst port 514` from the appserver (sending machine):

> <173>Jun 29 11:57:58 appserver acoder: 1.1.1.1 99.99.99.99 - -
>   [29/Jun/2015:11:57:58 -0400] "GET /somepage.php HTTP/1.1" 200 443 20

How do I remove the first few segments of the outbound log data?  Specifically:

```
Jun 29 11:57:58 appserver acoder:
```

I'd like that string removed so the only thing that is being sent is exactly what is in the access_log shown in the first quote above.

**httpd.conf**

```
#
# LogLevel: Control the number of messages logged to the error_log.
# Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
# alert, emerg.
#
# LogLevel warn
LogLevel debug

#
# The following directives define some format nicknames for use with
# a CustomLog directive (see below).

LogFormat "%h %A %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %p %b" combined
LogFormat "%h %A %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %p %b" common

LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent
```

**rsyslog.conf**

```
# rsyslog v5 configuration file

# For more information see /usr/share/doc/rsyslog-*/rsyslog_conf.html
# If you experience problems, see http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/troubleshoot.html

#### MODULES ####

$ModLoad imuxsock # provides support for local system logging (e.g. via logger command)
$ModLoad imklog   # provides kernel logging support (previously done by rklogd)

#### GLOBAL DIRECTIVES ####

# Use default timestamp format
$ActionFileDefaultTemplate RSYSLOG_TraditionalFileFormat

# Include all config files in /etc/rsyslog.d/
$IncludeConfig /etc/rsyslog.d/*.conf


#### RULES ####

# Log anything (except mail) of level info or higher.
# Don't log private authentication messages!
*.info;mail.none;authpriv.none;cron.none                /var/log/messages

# The authpriv file has restricted access.
authpriv.*                                              /var/log/secure

# Log all the mail messages in one place.
mail.*                                                  -/var/log/maillog

# Log cron stuff
cron.*                                                  /var/log/cron

# Everybody gets emergency messages
*.emerg                                                 *

# Save news errors of level crit and higher in a special file.
uucp,news.crit                                          /var/log/spooler

# Save boot messages also to boot.log
local7.*                                                /var/log/boot.log

# ### begin forwarding rule ###
# The statement between the begin ... end define a SINGLE forwarding
# rule. They belong together, do NOT split them. If you create multiple
# forwarding rules, duplicate the whole block!
# Remote Logging (we use TCP for reliable delivery)
#
# An on-disk queue is created for this action. If the remote host is
# down, messages are spooled to disk and sent when it is up again.

local5.*;local6.* @syslog.my.organization.tld:514

# ### end of the forwarding rule ###
```

Answer (score 0):

The parts that you're trying to remove are written by the receiving `rsyslog` daemon, not by the sender, and cannot be removed. They're part of the log format for `rsyslog`.

Comment: I'm viewing output sent from the app server with `tcpdump -vv -s 0 -A dst port 514`.   So you are saying that the rsyslog log format cannot be edited beyond what is done in httpd.conf's `LogFormat` section?

Comment: Yeah this answer is not fully correct.   I changed the log output by using `$template myFormat,"%msg%\n"` and `local5.*;local6.* @syslog.my.organization.tld:514;myFormat`.   Still have a bit of tweaking to do, but the text `Jun 29 11:57:58 appserver acoder:` is now gone.